# Does contracting a phrase change its undertone?

Tags: contracciones

When a phrase is contracted, does it change its undertone? That is, does it become more informal or more direct than its uncontracted version? For example, what are the differences between

`Dame un taco de cabeza` VS `¿Me da un taco de cabeza?`

and

`Quiero preguntarle` VS `Le quiero preguntar`

Comment: That isn't really a contraction, the only contractions in Spanish are `del`, `al`, etc.  the example that you gave is a gramatical construction that allows pronouns to be added onto the end of the verb. Ex: infinitive verbs, positive `tu` commands, and positive `vosotros` commands.

Comment: All the phrases you are listing such as _Dáme un taco de cabeza_ (informal) or _Me da un taco de cabeza_ (formal) are not contracted. Neither _Quiero preguntarle_ and _Le quiero preguntar_, in this case both are formal since you use the personal pronoun _le_ of _usted_.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the contracted form "Dámelo" is an order or a command, and the uncontracted "Me lo da?" is a question, as you can recognize for the question mark.
"Lo me da" is in incorrect order.

Comment: And is more casual, you can tell a friend ¡Dámelo! but you probably tell your boss: "Me lo da".

Comment: The question mark is for my question on this site. It is not part of the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, `Dámelo` is not a contraction and actually it is a grammatical structure that works as an order or like in the case of `me lo da?` as a polite request.

The tone changes since the way you request is different and probably you will choose one of them depending on who you are addressing (`Dámelo` is informal and direct, `me lo da?` is formal and polite). You may find this [review of Spanish grammatical structures](http://jlu.wbtrain.com/sumtotal/language/DLI%20basic%20courses/Spanish/Basic%20Course/Repaso%20De%20Las%20Estructuras%20Gramaticales.pdf) useful.

On the other hand, contractions are shortened versions of the written and spoken forms of a word or a group of words, and are created by omitting internal letters. The typical examples are:

> A + el = al
>
> De + el = del

There are other examples which are not so common(as far as I know) in Latin America such as:

> Donde + quiera = doquier
>
> De + esto = desto

I hope this helps!